# masstransit DI integration with asp.net core 2.0

Tags: masstransit

I have an application hosted on windows service based on MassTransit. It targets on .net framework 4.6.2. Now, I'm porting it to asp.net core 2.0. On .net framework I used autofac's containers for loading consumers from specify assembly. Now I want to use default asp.net core's DI for it. There is my startup code:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();

            services.RegisterAllTypes<IConsumer>(new Assembly[] { Assembly.Load("consumersLib") });

            var busControl = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
            {
                var host = cfg.Host(new Uri("rabbithost"), h =>{...});

                cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("queue", ec =>
                {
                    ec.LoadFrom(services.BuildServiceProvider());
                });

            });
        }
```

and Register:

```
public static void RegisterAllTypes<T>(this IServiceCollection services, Assembly[] assemblies,
        ServiceLifetime lifetime = ServiceLifetime.Transient)
        {
            var typesFromAssemblies = assemblies.SelectMany(a => a.DefinedTypes.Where(x => x.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(T))));
            foreach (var type in typesFromAssemblies)
                services.Add(new ServiceDescriptor(typeof(T), type, lifetime));
        }
```

ec.LoadFrom(services.BuildServiceProvider()) throws exception: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.", even though services.BuildServiceProvider() initialized and contains a few consumers. I looked at masstransit's source:

```
public static void LoadFrom(this IReceiveEndpointConfigurator configurator, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            var consumerCache = serviceProvider.GetService<IConsumerCacheService>();

            var consumers = consumerCache.GetConfigurators();

            foreach (var consumer in consumers)
                consumer.Configure(configurator, serviceProvider);

            var sagaCache = serviceProvider.GetService<ISagaCacheService>();

            IEnumerable<ICachedConfigurator> sagas = sagaCache.GetConfigurators();

            foreach (var saga in sagas)
                saga.Configure(configurator, serviceProvider);
        }
```

and I figured out a line serviceProvider.GetService() returns null. Does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

There is an integration library for using MassTransit with MS DI.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/MassTransit.Extensions.DependencyInjection/

It's also documented:

http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/usage/containers/msdi.html

Comment: Thanks of lot! It helped me.